# Visual Basic: Increasing integer every 3 clicks

Tags: visual-studio, vba, button, integer, increment

So my question is pretty much what the title says: how do I get a certain integer to increase by 1 for every three clicks of a button? For example, let's say the integer is 900. I click button1 once, then again, then again, and on the third click the integer changes to 901. How can this be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a variable called `count`, initialized to `0`. Every time the button is clicked, check the value of `count`. If `count <= 2` increment `count` else increment your special number and set `count` back to 0

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter that is actually three times larger behind the scene. Start at 2700 instead of 900, and increase the value by one for each click.

When you want to display the value that increases every third click, you divide the counter by three:

```
displayValue = counter \ 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe this could help or give you idea

```
Dim click = 0
Dim num = 900

if (click % 3 = 0)
   num+=1
else
 click+=1
end if
```